# The application "Navigator" can't be opened

Tags: anaconda

When I click on the navigator it says, `The application "Navigator" can't be opened` 
How can I fix this? It was completely fine few days ago and now I am trying to open it again and it says this suddenly. 
I tried updating it but still no result.
I am using Mac book `OS Sierra version 10.12.3`.

I tried updating the anaconda and navigator still not working

```
conda update anaconda
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

command line : `anaconda-navigator` gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 4, in <module>
    import anaconda_navigator.app.main
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QEvent, QObject, Qt
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Answer (score 24):

Have you tried launching from the command line? You can simply type:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

If you continue to have issues opening it this will at least provide a more descriptive traceback.

Comment: hey, Thanks i tried doing this earlier but didnt post the error form it. I have updated the question with it now.

Comment: What version of qtpy is on your system? You may want to run: "conda update qtpy"

Comment: I have the same *can't open* message but I can launch it from the command ling. Cant launch it by clicking on the application icon though

Answer (score 2):

I actually meet this problem too. My first time to download Anaconda and I use Macbook M1. My solution is open Navigator in finder. don't know the reason why it works in this way

Answer (score 0):

Been searching for solution for the same problem. Since I have uninstalled Anaconda completely and anaconda-navigator still won't launch after a fresh installation, I suspect that I messed up with my Windows system. And yes, the

vcruntime140_1.dll

file was accidentally removed.
I downloaded the file from https://dll-files.com and put it back in the system folder, and problem solved! anaconda-navigator is working again.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by opening a terminal and typing:

```
conda update pip
```

You can also test with this:

```
conda update -all
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, using MaxOS ventura 13.4.1 on M1 Machine.

***The only change I did since the last time is that, I've installed Anaconda-navigator in a different folder under my $HOME***

I'm able to manually launch is by going to anaconda folder and running the following command

```
./Anaconda-Navigator.app/Contents/MacOS/run.py
```

Once successful, we can just launch it from application.

Hope it helps